# NSNumber to float Value

Tags: ios

When I convert `NSNumber` to float value using 'floatValue', there is a difference in precision. Example, I have a `NSNumber` 'myNumber' having value 2.3, and if I convert myNumber to float using 'floatValue', its value becomes, 2.29999. But I need exactly 2.30000. There is no problem with number of zeros after 2.3, I need '2.3' instead of '2.9'.

How can I do so?

Comment: How are you storing the 2.3 in the `NSNumber` to begin with?

Comment: Have a look at `NSDecimalNumber`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had similar situation where I was reading value and assigning it back to float variable again.

My Problem statement:

```
 NSString *value = @"553637.90";
 NSNumber *num = @([value floatValue]); // 1. This is the problem. num is set to 553637.875000     
 NSNumberFormatter *decimalStyleFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [decimalStyleFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
 NSString *resultString = [decimalStyleFormatter stringFromNumber:num]; // 2. string is assigned with rounded value like 553637.88
 float originalValue = [resultString floatValue]; // 3. Hence, originalValue turns out to be 553637.88 which wrong.
```

Following worked for me after changing lines:

```
    NSNumber *num = @([value doubleValue]); // 4. doubleValue preserves value 553637.9
    double originalvalue = [resultString doubleValue]; // 5. While reading back, assign to variable of type double, in this case 'originalValue'
```

I hope this would be helpful. :)

Comment: I had the same issue. "99887766.12"  was parsing using floatValue to:  99887768.00 ( ??? ).    Changing it to doubleValue produces the correct value of 99887766.12.   Thanks.

Comment: I was working with 0.1137777777777778 and floatValue rounded to a whole different number. doubleValue worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you need exact precision, don't use `float`. Use a `double` if you need better precision. That still won't be exact. You could multiply myNumber by 10, convert to an unsigned int and perform your arithmetic on it, convert back to a float or double and divide by 10 and the end result might be more precise. If none of these are sufficiently precise, you might want to look into an arbitrary precision arithmetic library such as [GNU MP Bignum](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I've done the following but it is showing me correctly

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.3];
float f = [num floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f", f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with something like this:

```
  float x = 2.3f;
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:x];
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setPositiveFormat:@"0.#"];
NSString *s = [fmt stringFromNumber:n];
float f = [s floatValue];
```